# C++: Character Limit for Addressing Functions?

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I just fixed a bug in my project where a pointer reference went haywire because it was embedded too deep in the object layer. I guess my question is:

Does C++ have a char limit for referencing in general?

Comment: My favorite "low-level" definition of the pointer: A pointer is basically an integer, and index to an array called memory. High level programming languages just make the use of this index more easy and typesafe for you. If someone has programmed some lower level languages (e.g.: assembly) then he usually has no problems with concepts like pointers because of the previous definition...

Answer (score 3):

No, a pointer or reference is just a link from point A in memory to point B. The system doesn't care what kind of network is formed by those links.

Of course, the bigger the network, the more likely are mistakes. And every machine has its own ultimate limit on complexity, when it runs out of memory.

Comment: Brains give out long before that ;-)